# Can't install any package: "package linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic is missing final newline"?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, package-management, upgrade, software-updates

I tried to install some package updates on my Ubuntu 20.04.5, but everything fails with:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic' is missing final newline
```

How would I resolve this?

Here is the example I tried:

```
> sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-52-generic linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-52 linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  code docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin git git-man gitk gthumb gthumb-data libasn1-8-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libksba8 libroken18-heimdal libwind0-heimdal linux-generic-hwe-20.04
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-libc-dev unzip zlib1g zlib1g:i386 zlib1g-dev
28 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
23 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 0 B/286 MB of archives.
After this operation, 606 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
(base)  ~
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic.list` file is corrupt. You should move it out of the way, then `dpkg` will be able to proceed:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic.list{,.bak}
```

Ideally you would then reinstall the package so that `dpkg` can remove it properly, however that is probably no longer possible (the package isn’t available from the repositories). You should manually inspect the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic.list.bak` and delete any file listed there that doesn’t belong to any other package (use `dpkg -S` to check).

You may need to clean up `/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic` manually; check `/boot` too and remove corresponding `vmlinuz` and `initrd` files if any.

Comment: What caused all this?

Comment: I’d need a crystal ball to answer that...

Comment: What are the most common causes for such failures?

Comment: File system corruption (which doesn’t really answer the question, but it’s the best I can think of).